# Working fine with Spring JMS and getting problem with Apache camel route , IBM MQ Route

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, ibm-mq

I'm Sending request to the Third party IBM MQ with space pattern, like below text (COBOL input file), but i'm getting reponse as a error in Reply queue like below but same input working fine spring jms, i'm facing this problem with apache camel

**Sample Input:**

> GetProducerWithCommissionddRates
> C26115
> 77104  99998
> 2010-01-01                                011

**Response:**

> printing data in controller:: EPPRD02007EAn invalid COBOL Date Format
> was provided as input to the Producer Retrieval Service, Get Producer
> With Commission Rates Operation: AsOfDate.  Source:
> (ProducerMediationModule)
> ProducerMediationModule

**Controller with camel:**

```
@PostMapping("/request-reply")
    public String requestReplyMapping(@RequestBody String inputReq) {

        Exchange exchangeRequest = ExchangeBuilder.anExchange(camelContext).withBody(inputReq).build();
        Exchange exchangeResponse = producer.send("direct:request-reply", exchangeRequest);

        return exchangeResponse.getIn().getBody(String.class);

    }
```

**Camel Route:**

```
@Component
public class RequestReplyRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("direct:request-reply").
        to("jms:REQUEST.Q1?ReplyTo=REPLY.Q1&exchangePattern=InOut")
        .log("Request-reply Body is  ${body}   and header info is   ${headers}  ");

         from("jms:REPLY.Q1")
        .log("Received Body is  ${body}   and header info is   ${headers}  ");
    }

}
```

**JMS Controller Code(working) :**

```
 @PostMapping(value="request-reply") 
public ResponseEntity<String> sendRequestAndReceiveReply (@RequestBody String prd2x4Request) { System.out.println("received prd2x4 request: "+prd2x4Request); 
String reply = prd2x4Wrapper.sendReqAndGetMessageId(prd2x4Request); 
return new ResponseEntity<String>(reply, HttpStatus.OK); 

}
```

JMS MQ Calling (working) :

```
private String sendReqAndGetMessage(String prd2x4Request) { 
String messageId = ""; 
MQQueue requestQueue = new MQQueue(RequestQueue);
 Session session = jmsTemplate.getConnectionFactory().createConnection().createSession(); MessageProducer mp = session.createProducer(requestQueue); 
TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(prd2x4Request);
 message.setStringProperty("JMS_IBM_Character_Set", "IBM037"); 
mp.send(message);
 messageId = message.getJMSMessageID(); 
mp.close();
 session.close(); 
return messageId; 
}
```

Comment: this looks like a problem while passing the date value to ibm-mq

Comment: i'm passing date as it is with spaces, i'm facing this problem with camel only and i't working fine with spring jms template

Comment: Could you please add your working code too?

Comment: i think i comment section don't have text format, i added code , could you please check it once

Comment: I edited the question, could anyone please help to resolve the issue

Comment: What is `JMS_IBM_Character_Set`? Is it required? It doesn’t appear in your Camel solution but it does appear in your Spring JMS solution.

Comment: Good point issue is there with JMS_IBM_Character_Set property only, could you please tell how to override the MQ default properties, here I have to set JMS_IBM_Character_Set= UTF-8 , default values is JMS_IBM_Character_Set=IBM037

Comment: I'm trying to write like this exchangeRequest.setProperty("JMS_IBM_Character_Set", "UTF-8"); but it's not overriding default value

Comment: CCSID 37 is EBCDIC indicating that you are sending this message to a mainframe (supported by the fact that the error message mentions COBOL.  The likely explanation is that the COBOL app does not issue a get with convert (`MQGMO-CONVERT`), the result is that the message you send where you specify CCSID 37 is readable to the app as no conversion is needed but when you send it from Camel JMS defaults to UTF-8 (CCSID 1208) and the message would be unreadable.  One solution would be for the COBOL app to add `MQGMO-CONVERT` to there GET options, the queue manager would handle the conversion.

Comment: If you don't connect directly to the mainframe and instead connect to another queue manager which then sends the message to the mainframe queue manager, another  "solution" that I don't typically recommend would be to set `CONVERT(YES)` on the Sender (`SDR`) channel which goes from the queue manager you connect to over to the mainframe.

Comment: I'm not much good at mainframe and MQ technical words, I'm a beginner in this area, could you please tell any code snippet for solving this issue

Comment: why do you keep opening up new questions?

Comment: because it's somewhat priority one, for getting quick response I'm making a new question